# count value input field when click on a value jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a input field and links with values. when click on a link the value go to the input field. when clicking a other link the value is not count with the value that already is in the input field. example:

```
<form name="odenen_form">
<input type="text"     
class="input_text"name="odenen_miktar"id="odenen_miktar"    
style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:50px;width:200px">
</form>

<a onClick="document.odenen_form.odenen_miktar.value+='10'">10</a>
<a onClick="document.odenen_form.odenen_miktar.value+='20'">20</a>
```

Now when i click on the first link the input field shows me 10
when i click again on the first link the input field shows 1010

Wat i want is 20 as result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you tagged jQuery, here is a nicely formatted jQuery example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Milanzor/gZ7ZG/

```
<form name="odenen_form">
<input type="text"     
class="input_text"name="odenen_miktar"id="odenen_miktar"    
    style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:50px;width:200px" />
</form>

<a>10</a>
<a>20</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //The value to add: parseInt is what you want
        var toAdd = parseInt($(this).text());

        //The current value
        var currentVal = $("#odenen_miktar").val();

        //Check if its not empty or if its not a number
        if(currentVal == '' || parseInt(currentVal) == 'NaN'){
         var currentNumber = 0;   
        }else{
         var currentNumber = parseInt($("#odenen_miktar").val());
        }

        //The new value
        var newValue = toAdd + currentNumber;

        //Put the new value in the input field
        $("#odenen_miktar").val(newValue);

    });

});
```

Comment: when i use parseFloat its only count before the point. example 10.99 + 10.01 = 20.99 and not 21

Answer (score 1):

You're doing string concatenation rather than math. `"10"` is not the same as `10` -- also, parse your `input`!

```
<a onClick=" parseInt(document.odenen_form.odenen_miktar.value) += 10 ">10</a>
```

Comment: This works thanms but and when i use 10.99 is not working shows only 10

Comment: Use `parseDouble` for doubles!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
<form name="odenen_form">
    <input type="text" class="input_text"name="odenen_miktar"id="odenen_miktar" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:50px;width:200px"/>
</form>

<a onClick="var a=document.odenen_form.odenen_miktar;a.value=a.value?parseInt(a.value)+10:10">10</a>
<a onClick="var a=document.odenen_form.odenen_miktar;a.value=a.value?parseInt(a.value)+20:20">20</a>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NQrE7/)